# JavaScript Get Data From Other Site

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JS and have a question. Would it be possible to pull data off from another website to use in your own? For example, say I have a JS web app that lets a user input their Twitter username and then the script goes to this username and looks for the follower count element and pulls that number off to display back in the web app. I'm sure there are APIs and such to do something like that specific Twitter example, but I'm getting more at the general idea of being able to access data on other sites. How can it be done? Surely there is a way if my browser can access all of that information, right? Would you have to put an invisible iFrame into the app and search through it with JS?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

To put it in basic terms for a newbie, this is only possible if the website in question has an API, specifically designed to allow outside access. Sometimes they're pretty easy to understand and set up.

Accessing the content of an outside website in a way it wasn't really designed to support has happened, but it's usually what's known as "hacking". It's sometimes easy to do for very basic types of sites, but most sites that request login information forbid it. (Except through aforementioned APIs). The biggest concern is that if someone is already logged in to Twitter on their browser, an outside site of questionable origin could automatically post bad things to your account while you're not even apparently visiting Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

The best approach is to use **ajax** (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) with **[jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)** (Javascript Object Notation with Padding) datatype.

To use this method the server you are going to connect should be expecting the request so it can response with jsonp (it's just a json data wrapped by a callback function you defined when you make the request).

The process:

1) Your code make an ajax request to the other server adding a callback function to the url. It's very commom to use "**callback**" param name, but the server can define the variable name it prefers.

```
http://other-server-url.com/?callback=myFunction
```

A good and easy approach here is to use jQuery. If you define *dataType:"jsonp"* in your ajax call, jQuery handles the process of appending the callback and execute the right function when you get the response. It's a good idea to take a look at [jQuery's ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and read a little about jsonp cross domain requests.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    url: "http://other-server.com/",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) { // this function will be executed when you get the response
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

- this jQuery method only works if the param name is **callback**. If it isn't, you should handle by your own, or take a deeper look at documentation to know how to do it with jQuery.

2) The server should be waiting for these "callback" param and response your request with a jsonp data format. It's just [json data format](http://json.org/) wrapped by the function you passed as the callback. Like this:

```
myFunction({ json-data });
```

3) When you get the response, the **myFunction** function will be executed automatically, with the json data as the parameter:

```
function myFunction(myData) {
    console.log(myData); // this will log the data on the browser console
}
```

I hope I have helped. Good coding.